# cannot find -lslink

Tags: 12.04, software-installation, make, ld

While running `make` for a program installation on ubuntu 12.04 LTS, I was stuck with the following error:

Could anyone help explain the cause and solution please? I'm a rookie please...

Thanks

```
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /home/user/DINVER_3/geopsypack-57items-src-2.5.0/lib/libslink.a when searching for -lslink
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lslink
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [../bin/geopsy] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/user/DINVER_3/geopsypack-57items-src-2.5.0/geopsy'
make[1]: *** [release] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/user/DINVER_3/geopsypack-57items-src-2.5.0/geopsy'
make: *** [sub-geopsy-make_default-ordered] Error 2
```

Answer (score 1):

The GNU linker cannot find the shared library called `slink` or `libslink`.

You have to install this, but this library is not in the ubuntu standard repositories it is part of the `gropsy` package and there is a PPA for this on [Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/~soroush-r/+archive/geopsy-deb).

Add the PPA into your sources.list: add the following two lines to `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/soroush-r/geopsy-deb/ubuntu precise main 
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/soroush-r/geopsy-deb/ubuntu precise main
```

and then run:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

And install the `geopsy` and the `libslink` package:

```
sudo apt-get install geopsy libslink
```

After this your error should not raise again.